# Nodejs synchronous HTTP request

Tags: node.js, httprequest, synchronous

For Example: Consider a user registration web service in nodejs. Inside the function I have written code for validating email existence in DB(also the entire function is written using asyn await). This is working when single request is made at a time. When multiple registration api calls are made with the same email_id, this validation won't works. Please let me know if any one faced the similar issue before and a solution for the same.

Comment: That is the problem with single threaded asynchronous nature of JavaScript. You can go through following blog post, this will help you fix your problem. http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2014/03/22/a-pattern-for-handling-concurrent/

Comment: how could we solve it ? making it multi threaded ?, if so how.

Comment: If it's working correctly for single req, then it should also work for multiple. Did you find it failing for multiple req or it's just your thought? 
Can you explain the exact problem you are facing when multiple req executed?

Comment: Exact problem: If multiple http request are called for user-registartion api(at same time), same email is inserting in to the DB irrespective of the validation. If the request are made one by one(one at a time) then the validation will work.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati it is not that way, while registering he is checking if email exists if not he is adding one. But if he makes 2 concurrent requests, one will check for existence of email ID and second request will wait for that time. Once first request done with read it will try for insert operation. Meanwhile second request will read the document, since the record is not inserted yet, it won't get any result. Then record gets inserted and then second request again makes write operation.

Comment: When properly trained, one can write reliable asynchronous code that handles zillions of requests in flight at the same time.  If you posted your actual code, we might even be able to show you how in your context.  But, writing a generic tutorial on how to do that without any of your code is beyond the scope of stack overflow.  node.js does not support synchronous networking and the threaded infrastructure that would be needed for that.  If you want that, pick a language that works that way such as Java.  Or, learn how to write proper asynchronous Javascript to solve your problem.

Comment: From the help center: ***Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).***

Comment: You can handle this simply by adding unique constraint on email. This way you will get duplicate entry error on mongo for second request (all requests after 1st insert). Use mongoose like following

``var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email:  {type: String, unique: true},
... other properties.
});``

Comment: @Sandip Nirmal, the solution you provided is DB level and I want it to be in code level. Consider I want to implement some other business logic validation and not just email unique validation. If so how could we achieve that.

Comment: If you're talking about avoiding race conditions on shared business logic data, solutions are not generic, but are specific to the particular problem.   Show your code and your precise problem.  A generic tutorial on this topic is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer and makes a question like that far too broad and non-specific and thus considered "off-topic" here and subject to getting closed.

Comment: In order to achieve uniqueness you must have it on DB level. Other solutions will fail in some case. If somehow you are able to achieve restriction on only one registration request at one time, then it will hamper backend performance. This way there can be only one registration request at a time.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430384/mongodb-insert-if-it-doesnt-exist-else-skip/32430736

Answer (score 1):

Your mongoose schema should be something in following format:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    firstName:  {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

}));
```

This will throw error `E11000 duplicate key error` in case you try to make second registration with same email. You need to handle this error in your response to notify user that account with particular `email` already exists.

Comment: I want some other solution like synchronising http request and DB level blocking/validation

Comment: Synchronising HTTP request will hamper your backend performance. If you make registration request synchronous no other registration request will be allowed to make during that time.

In other way you can also have some sort of data structure in place which can hold your registration request for email Ids, and you can check every request against it. But this too will face similar issue at sometime.

I am still not in favour of having this handled from code rather than having a DB constraint. And I don't know what is the reason you want it to be handled from code.