# NodeJS MongoDb updateMany() with a condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update a MongoDb collection with an Array of JSON objects.
However, I want the update to ignore any objects that already exist in the DB.
Sounds easy, but the key that allows me to know if the object exists is not the '_id', but a different 'id' (or other key).
Is that possible ?

Currently I am using it like this:

```
dbHandle.collection('contents').updateMany(contents);
```

where 'contents' is the Array of JSON objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are not looking for an `update` since you don't want to alter any existing record... this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430384/mongodb-insert-if-it-doesnt-exist-else-skip/32430736

Comment: So I see that the code in the link you posted is not using updateMany but updateOne - so not realy a bulk operation

Comment: It would be useful to have an example of the documents in the database and an example of the contents variable and what the expected outcome is

Comment: could you please show some example for your array of objects

Answer (score 3):

The following operation updates all documents where violations are greater than 4 and $set a flag for review:

```
try {
   db.restaurant.updateMany(
      { violations: { $gt: 4 } },  //Your Condition
      { $set: { "Review" : true } }  //YOUR JSON contents
   ); 
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

Change the condition accordingly.

Comment: Not really.
It would be more like this : (psuedo)

try {
   db.restaurant.updateMany(
      { id: { $ne: [any 'id' that exist] } },  //Your Condition
      { $set: { "Review" : true } }  //YOUR JSON contents
   ); 
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}